# New Unity input system not working/responding

Tags: unity, c#, input

I'm trying to use the new input system for my 3rd person character in Unity. However, whenever I press the WASD keys, or try to move the camera, nothing happens. I've looked everywhere, but can't find an answer!

Here's a picture of the different values and such.
[image]

Here's some of my code

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour {

    [Header("Mouse Input Settings")]
    public bool cursorLocked = true;
    public bool cursorInputForLook = true;

    public void OnMove(InputValue value)
    {
        Debug.Log("Moving");
        move = value.Get<Vector2>();
    }

    
    public void OnLook(InputValue value)
    {

        Debug.Log("Looking");
        if (cursorInputForLook)
        { 
           look = value.Get<Vector2>();
            
        }
    }

    public void OnJump(InputValue value)
    {
        Debug.Log("Jumping");
        jump = value.isPressed;
    }

    public void OnSprint(InputValue value)
    {
        Debug.Log("Sprinting");
        sprint = value.isPressed;
    }
}
```

*I also have the active input handling turned to both input systems in the projected settings menu.* What could I possibly be doing wrong? Is my project just bugged, and I have to just make a new one? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This looks quite similar to [this existing Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65484137) — did you try applying the answer posted there?

Comment: Yeah I already did, however the console still isn't logging whenever I press the WASD keys or when I try to look around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just using the documentation as an answer for your case (since I usually do the binding of via code and not the editor)

The binding of your events for `player input` should be `Behaviour: Invoke Unity Events` according to the [docu](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.6/manual/Workflow-PlayerInput.html). From there you can set the methods you want to call in your `character controller`.

[image: work flow from the documentation]